# React component rendering multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was playing around with React a bit and I'm facing a spicy issue which I can't figure out.

I have a *Joke* Component which is basically supposed to make a request to `https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2` and display the results. Making the request and updating my state is all done in a method, which is then called in the componentDidMount() method.

This works perfectly fine, but I wanted to make the component make more requests to the API on click, so what I tried doing was setting the Component's onClick value equal to the method that makes the XMLHttpRequest.

My issue is that doing this makes my page spam the api with requests, so there are various jokes being requested per one click, whereas I just want one joke per click.

The code's right below:

```
class Joke extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      joke: '',
      hover: false
    };
    this.getJoke = this.getJoke.bind(this);
  }

//GET request for the joke
getJoke = () => {
    let that = this;
    // this.setState({ joke: '' });
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        console.log(this.response);
        that.setState({ joke: this.response })
      }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Programming,Miscellaneous?blacklistFlags=nsfw,racist,sexist&format=txt');
    xhr.send();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getJoke();
  }

  render() {
    let jokeClass = 'text' + (this.state.hover ? '' : ' shy');
    console.log(jokeClass);

    console.log(this.state.joke);

    return (
      <div id='joke' className={jokeClass} onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ hover: true })} onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ hover: false })} onClick={this.getJoke()}>
        <p id='qualityContent'>
          {!this.state.hover && 'Hover over me for a joke.\nClick me for another one.'}
          {this.state.joke.length > 0 && this.state.hover && this.state.joke}
          {this.state.joke.length === 0 && this.state.hover && 'Joke incoming'}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate any insight you guys can give me :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use onClick in react.js?](//stackoverflow.com/q/51832797/90527)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onClick={() => this.getJoke()}` or `onClick={this.getJoke}`. Currently you are running this function when render is called and a result of it would be assigned to onClick.

**Edit:**

One of the mentioned version should be used instead of `onClick={this.getJoke()}` on `<div>` element.

The reason is that by setting `onClick={this.getJoke()}` you tell React on render to call your `getJoke` method and assign a result of it as a `onClick` handler for runtime. Now, because `getJoke()` is making a request and setting a state value, here's what happens:

1. React renders your component, runs `this.getJoke()`
2. Make a request
3. Set result on a state `that.setState({ joke: this.response })`
4. Because state changed, React is going to re-render your component, but again there is `onClick={this.getJoke()}` so your method would be called.
5. Go back to point 2 (causing an infinite loop)

Comment: Hey, sorry. I am setting the onClick in the parent div encapsulating all of it's children in render at the very right. Are you saying that I can't call the function under componentDidMount() and make it an onclick function?

Comment: @deenhaque Jakub means, replace your `onClick={this.getJoke()}` with `onClick={() => this.getJoke()}`

Comment: Yes, that's right. @CiBoz Thanks for clarification  :)

Comment: Added some explanation to the answer